# Hierarchical (URN) ex(urn:serviceid:partitionId:parent:child) scripted custom attribute in OPEN DJ

Tags: ldap, opendj

I am trying to build a custom attribute in OPEN DJ / LDAP which should be like a custom urn to uniquely identify a resource by resource id which is URN . like a person would be identified by his urn (urn:org:partion:manager:person)

Answer (score 0):

There is no URN syntax in LDAP, but you can always use DirectoryString or IA5String as the syntax for your attribute. Alternately in OpenDJ you can define your own syntax using Regular expression, to constrain the values you can store in your attribute.